# Issue with jQuery html() concatenation

Tags: jquery

Can you please let me know why the concatenation is not working in this html()?

```
$("#clickMe").click(function() {
  $('.output').text($("Welcome"+'input:text'+" !").val());
});
```

an you can see I am trying to render the users input from text box between to strings

Comment: First of all : what errors is your console firing?
Second: `($("Welcome"+'input:text'+" !").val())` what are you triyng to select? It seems to be here the error..
Give us some html also.

Comment: What's the code for the input you are trying to get the text from?

Comment: Ok I think I get point. so the val() function is getting the value from the text box but in this case how we can concat string with that value?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are concatenating in the wrong place... no need to wrap the string in `$()`.

`$('.output').text( "Welcome, " + $('input').val() + "!" );`